# adobe flash based tablet?

Tags: flash, tablet

anybody ever come up with idea like, a tablet that run only adobe flash ?

or for making such device , what could be minimum system software and hardware requirement ?

AND , is licences of flash/adobe allows it in first place ?

Answer (score 0):

I know that BlackBerry's Playbook is doing something very similar, but not sure to what degree. 
From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlackBerry_PlayBook):

> Among the features demonstrated was its tight integration with and support for Adobe AIR applications and full Flash support